# Remotely adding/removing components in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, modular

I want to use ReactJS for the front end of our new system.

The back end system (in C#) has different modules which can be toggled on/off.  Each module has its own set of DLLs, meaning the product can be "shipped" without unnecessary module DLLs.  "You need chat functionality? Here's the DLL, drop it in your bin folder, good to go!"

Each DLL is pretty much standalone with no dependency on an other, apart from it's main parent abstraction.

I would like to know, is it possible to create something similar in a React front end? I don't want to have hundreds of react components listed with a bunch of 'if' statements to show/hide them.

I would like each module to be responsible for its own rendering & actions. Adding a brand new feature would be as easy as 'building the extra module' (not updating the 'core' system files to tell it about the extra module).

Gah, I hope that makes sense! Could anyone point me in the right direction? Is this a fools errand? Is it achievable?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is more question of how to split your frontend code than react specific question. Good news is, it's certainly possible. Take a look at [webapack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/) - bundling tool often use with react. I am not sure how exactly modules and DLLs work in C#, but I imagine you have some way how to include different js bundles into them. If so, webpack will help you create these bundles.